# Calling too many overloaded methods - only want one

Tags: c#, overloading

Learning C# on my own (not homework).  Program is calling all 3 overloaded methods - should only call one method based on the user's input type (int, double, or string).  How do I do this?  Do I use an if statement with the methods?  Basic/simple answer please.  Thank you!!

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int entryInt;
        double entryDouble;
        string entryString;
        string userEntry;

        const double MIN = 10.00;

        Console.WriteLine("\t** WELCOME TO THE AUCTION! **\n");
        Console.Write("Please enter a bid for the item:  ");
        userEntry = Console.ReadLine();

        int.TryParse(userEntry, out entryInt);
        double.TryParse(userEntry, out entryDouble);
        entryString = userEntry.ToLower();

        BidMethod(entryInt, MIN);
        BidMethod(entryDouble, MIN);
        BidMethod(entryString, MIN);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void BidMethod(int bid, double MIN)
    {  // OVERLOADED - ACCEPTS BID AS AN INT
        Console.WriteLine("Bid is an int.");
        Console.WriteLine("Your bid is: {0:C}", bid);
        if (bid >= MIN)
            Console.WriteLine("Your bid is over the minimum {0} bid amount.", MIN);
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Your bid is not over the minimum {0} bid amount.", MIN);
    }

    private static void BidMethod(double bid, double MIN)
    {  // OVERLOADED - ACCEPTS BID AS A DOUBLE

        Console.WriteLine("Bid is a double.");
        Console.WriteLine("Your bid is: {0:C}", bid);
        if (bid >= MIN)
            Console.WriteLine("Your bid is over the minimum {0} bid amount.", MIN);
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Your bid is not over the minimum {0} bid amount.", MIN);
    }

    private static void BidMethod(string bid, double MIN)
    {  // OVERLOADED - ACCEPTS BID AS A STRING

        string amount;
        int amountInt;

        if (bid.StartsWith("$")) 
            amount = (bid as string).Trim('$');  // Remove the $
        if (bid.EndsWith("dollar"))
            amount = bid.TrimEnd(' ', 'd', 'o', 'l', 'l', 'a', 'r', 's');
        else
            amount = bid;

        Int32.TryParse(amount, out amountInt);  // Convert to Int
        Console.WriteLine("Bid is a string.");

        Console.WriteLine("Your bid is: {0:C}", bid);
        if (amountInt >= MIN)
            Console.WriteLine("Your bid is over the minimum {0} bid amount.", MIN);
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Your bid is not over the minimum {0} bid amount.", MIN);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: If you only want to call one of the methods, you need to write code to  only call one of the methods.  Use `if` statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The design here is not great, but anyway. Notice that `TryParse` methods return boolean value indicating whether they succeded or failed to parse the string. You can use this to decide what method to call:

```
if (int.TryParse(userEntry, out entryInt))
{
    BidMethod(entryInt, MIN);
}
else if (double.TryParse(userEntry, out entryDouble))
{
    BidMethod(entryDouble, MIN);
}
else
{        
    entryString = userEntry.ToLower();
    BidMethod(entryString, MIN);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (int.TryParse(...))
    BidMethod(entryInt, MIN);
else if (double.TryParse(...))
    BidMethod(entryDouble, MIN);
...
...
```